Is it possible to use '\1[2:3]' in substitute?
During :s command line substitute, after matching I can use abc\2,cde\1 this kind of syntax to format the output, however, seems it's not possible to use abc\2[3:-1],cde\1[2:3] to take a substring from matched result.
The work-around I now use is to \=printf("abc%s,cde%s", submatch(2)[3:-1], submatch(1)[2:3]) but of course this is a bit long.
Is there a way to directly use syntax similar to \1[2:3] in the command line?

The special replacement syntaxes are all documented at :help sub-replace-special. Since \<n>[slice] isn't documented there, the only way to do specifically what you want is to use the \= + submatch() + [slice] syntax from the original question. Breaking up the matches in the pattern is also viable, as Vivian demonstrates.
You could also try to build a function that can expand occurences of \[\d]\[-\?\d\+:-\?\d\+] into the submatch code, which you could then hook up to a keybinding or autocommand to automatically generate the right code for you. But that might be more effort than it's worth.

"build a function that can expand occurences of [\d][-?\d+:-?\d+] into the submatch code" -- do you mean extend the current vim's c++ code and recompile?

No, I meant in vimscript @athos. PS Vim is written in (mostly) C.

I would split \1 at catching time.
e.g.:
Instead of:
/\v"([^"]*)"

I would do:
/\v"([^"]{2})([^"]{0,2})([^"]*)"

Now:

\1 corresponds to the first two characters
\2 corresponds to the next two characters
\3 corresponds to the rest


yeah this is an alternative...
